# Block scripts with specific url

Tags: javascript, html

i`ve a html document and load a script inside it like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>   
  <meta charset="utf-8">

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

My question is, if there is a way to block the script call from the origin `code.jquery.com` by adding a script before it which scans it and block it then.

I didn't find anything about it.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent script from running using the following functions that I wrote.
`blockScript` will loop through all script tags and remove any script tag's source that includes the origin that you provide. Please note that this uses [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) API and it will remove all matching script tags.

### BlockScript

```js
function blockScript(origin) {
    const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));
    if (scripts.length > 0) {
        scripts.forEach((script) => {
            if (script.src.includes(origin)) {
                document.head.removeChild(script);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### MutationObserver

And using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), you can watch for DOM changes.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        const addedNodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
        if (addedNodes && addedNodes.some(n => n.nodeName === 'SCRIPT')) {
            blockScript('code.jquery.com');
        }
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

And put everything together ...

```html
<script>
    function blockScript(origin) {
        const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));
        if (scripts.length > 0) {
            scripts.forEach((script) => {
                if (script.src.includes(origin)) {
                    document.head.removeChild(script);
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
            const addedNodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
            if (addedNodes && addedNodes.some(n => n.nodeName === 'SCRIPT')) {
                blockScript('code.jquery.com');
            }
            observer.disconnect();
        }
    });
    observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('I am undefined');
    })
</script>
```

You should get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I've only tested this using Chrome.